# Asbestos Floor Sealant

Tags: asbestos

Just bought my first home and it is a slab foundation with what our inspector believed to be some kind of asbestos tile under the carpet for the whole house. We plan to tear up all the carpet and replace with different flooring(some carpet, ceramic, and laminate wood). The common sentiment I see is to seal the asbestos floor rather than remove it as long as it is in good condition, which it is. However, I never really see suggestions for what to use for sealing it besides PerfectPrimer.

Does anyone have experience with this and what kind/brand of sealant they used? The house is 1500sqft, so PerfectPrimer would be about $1,500 for the whole place which is pretty pricey.

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Unless it is to have rough use(like sanding) a sealant probably only makes you feel good.  To tell asbestos it needs testing.  If not sanding it without a mask, putting your money into new flooring is better or some floor paint.

Comment: I would just paint it, to stop loose fibres coming off.